# How to insert many tikzpicture R plot images as .tex files inside a table of images in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, r, tikzdevice

I can include my R plots in a LaTeX document using tikz package (on the LaTeX side) and tikzDevice package on the R side. I produced many .tex files containing my plots in R using as an example the following code in R:

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz(file = 'BarplotScreenType.tex', width = 3, height = 3)
barplot(height=table(screentype),main="", xlab="Types of screens",  ylab="Count", ylim=c(0,12),  col="blue")
dev.off()`
```

What I need to do is to include all these .tex files in a nice border-less table of images in the LaTeX document. 
I previously used a piece of code (shown below) that allowed me to put png images using `\raisebox{-.1\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=0.3\textheight, inner]{AchavanichOriginalCROPED1}}`:

```
\begin{table*}[!htbp] 
\caption{Table showing decimated images of Achavanich Beaker(original 
resolution was 6.1M faces - 1st picture on left)}\label{table:images}
\centering
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{8.9cm}p{8.2cm}}
\raisebox{-.1\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, 
height=0.3\textheight, inner]           
{AchavanichOriginalCROPED1}}&\raisebox{-.1\height}
{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=0.3\textheight, inner]
{Achavanich3MCROPED3}} \\
\raisebox{-.1\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,     
 height=0.3\textheight, inner]

{Achavanich15MCROPED2}}&\raisebox{-.1\height}
{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, 

height=0.3\textheight, inner]{Achavanich750KCROPED2}} \\
\raisebox{-.1\height}{\includegraphics

[width=0.5\textwidth, height=0.3\textheight, inner]
{Achavanich300KCROPED}}&\raisebox

{-.1\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=0.3\textheight, 
inner]

{Achavanich100KCROPED}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

\includegraphics does not support .tex as an extension even .tex files contain a blocks of \tikzpicture commands.

Another important thing: I need a caption for each figure and a label (for cross referencing...).

Any ideas of how that might be done? Any better suggestions would also be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\input` instead of `\includegraphics`.  Do not forget to set the proper width and height of your graphic chunks

Example:

```
tikz(file="cars.tex", width=2, height=2)
par(mar=c(2,2,0.5,0.5))
plot(cars, xlab="", ylab="")
dev.off()

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \input{cars} & \input{cars}\\
  \input{cars} & \input{cars}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Boris Kindly, how do I put a caption and label so I can reference it from LaTeX side? Do you know? If I put the "\include{}" like the following " \begin{figure} \include{graph1} \caption{M1} \label{fig:M1} \end{figure}", I receive an error.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out the solution. Using the package \usepackage{subcaption} and inside the table I can then put the following form:   \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\centering \include{barplotGraph} \caption{Figure A: Graph 1} \label{fig:taba} \end{subfigure}

Comment: Great.  There are several ways to do this;  this is a good one.